# Torch7: Slice Tensor using ByteTensor mask

Tags: torch

I have two tensors:

1. labels is a 1D Tensor (5000)
2. dataset is  4D Tensor (5000,1,32,32)

I would like to efficiently slice the labels and dataset corresponding to label of value 1. I succeed in slicing the labels but not the dataset.

Slicing the labels:

```
positive_mask = labels:eq(1)
sliced_labels = labels[positive_mask]
```

I tried doing the following to slice the dataset and failed:

```
sliced_dataset = dataset[positive_mask]
sliced_dataset = dataset[{positive_mask, {}, {}, {}}]
sliced_dataset = dataset:narrow(1,positive_mask)
sliced_dataset = dataset:select(1,positive_mask)
```

Is there an **elegant** approach to perform this in Torch7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sliced_dataset = dataset:index(1, positive_mask:nonzero():squeeze())
```